# What kind of Javascript color codes are these?

Tags: javascript

i came across this JS code i would like to know what kind of color codes are example: 00190705
do any of you know what it is and how do I generate others?
because I need to add others or modify existing ones and I can't find them anywhere online.

code:

````
  "items" : [ {
    "guid" : "BCC-21188_20181108_DYE_01_01",
    "color_intensities" : "100",
    "color_number" : "BR-1",
    "colors" : {
      "color" : "0037211a"
    },
    "shine_intensities" : "50",
    "sku_guid" : "BCC-21188_20181108_DYE_01",
    "hair_dye_mode" : "salon",
    "itemLongName" : "Auburn brown"
  }, {
    "guid" : "BCC-21188_20181108_DYE_01_02",
    "color_intensities" : "100",
    "color_number" : "BR-2",
    "colors" : {
      "color" : "000b0604"
    },
    "shine_intensities" : "50",
    "sku_guid" : "BCC-21188_20181108_DYE_01",
    "hair_dye_mode" : "salon",
    "itemLongName" : "Chocolate brown"
  }, {
    "guid" : "BCC-21188_20181108_DYE_01_03",
    "color_intensities" : "100",
    "color_number" : "BR-3",
    "colors" : {
      "color" : "00030201"
    },
    "shine_intensities" : "50",
    "sku_guid" : "BCC-21188_20181108_DYE_01",
    "hair_dye_mode" : "salon",
    "itemLongName" : "Dark brown"
  }, {
    "guid" : "BCC-21188_20181108_DYE_01_04",
    "color_intensities" : "100",
    "color_number" : "BR-4",
    "colors" : {
      "color" : "005c4630"
    },
    "shine_intensities" : "50",
    "sku_guid" : "BCC-21188_20181108_DYE_01",
    "hair_dye_mode" : "salon",
    "itemLongName" : "Light brown"
  }, {
    "guid" : "BCC-21188_20181108_DYE_01_05",
    "color_intensities" : "100",
    "color_number" : "BR-5",
    "colors" : {
      "color" : "002c1d11"
    },
    "shine_intensities" : "50",
    "sku_guid" : "BCC-21188_20181108_DYE_01",
    "hair_dye_mode" : "salon",
    "itemLongName" : "Warm brown" ```

thank you
````

Comment: look like regular ones with `00` tacked on to the front for no reason except to confuse

Comment: Thats probably [RGBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space), where the last 2 digits are for the ALPHA chanel

Comment: @0stone0 no they are not - because then none of those would have any red in them, yet they're mostly described as some sort of brown - which definitely has red in it :p

Comment: @0stone0 : I doubt hex value '1a' in '0037211a' would represent alpha

Comment: @0stone0 the *first* two digits are more likely the alpha channel.

Comment: @Alnitak - so, they're all 100% transparent?? also makes no sense :p

Comment: @Bravo, true, it could just be padding.

Answer (score 8):

They look like 32-bit hexadecimal "XXRRGGBB" (X for unused), where the highest byte is 00.

Since the highest byte doesn't matter, you can just replace it with a `#` to get a regular #RRGGBB hex color color, e.g.

```
"002c1d11".replace(/^00/, '#')
```

to get

```
'#2c1d11'
```

which is indeed a very dark brown:

[image]